# Code listing for arduino language?

Tags: listings

I've been trying to use the `listings` package. The problem is that I don't know how to put different colors to the different key words.

With my code I can only get some of the keywords to be an specific color, like when I use "LOW," "HIGH," "int" or "float," but I want to get a different color when I use, for example, "begin," "pinMode" or "setCursor." How can I do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset
{
    frame=single,
    framesep=\fboxsep,
    framerule=\fboxrule,
    rulecolor=\color{red},
    xleftmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
    xrightmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\small\tt,
    keywordstyle=\color{cyan}\sf,
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    commentstyle=\color{cyan},
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},
    tabsize=2,
    columns=flexible,
    morekeywords={LOW,HIGH,int,float,const,void,OUTPUT},
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(7,6,5,4,3,2);
int SENSOR;
float TEMPERATURA;
float SUMA;
const int MOTOR=13;

void setup() {
 lcd.begin(16,2);
 pinMode(MOTOR, OUTPUT);
 lcd.setCursor(1,0);
 lcd.print("COOLING SYSTEM");
 delay(3000);
 lcd.clear();
 }

void loop() {
  SUMA = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < 5; i++){
    SENSOR = analogRead(A0);
    TEMPERATURA = ((SENSOR*5000.0)/1023)/10;
    SUMA = TEMPERATURA + SUMA;
    delay(100);
  }
  if (TEMPERATURA > 35 ){
    lcd.clear();
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Ventilador ON");
  }
  else{
    lcd.clear();
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Ventilador OFF");
  }

 lcd.setCursor(0,0);
 lcd.print("Temp: ");
 lcd.print(SUMA/5.0,1);
 lcd.print(" C");
}
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

[image]

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a classoffset parameter you can set to create different groups of highlighting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{arduinoOrange}{RGB}{210,83,102}
\definecolor{arduinoGrayGreen}{RGB}{94,109,3}

\lstset
{
    frame=single,
    framesep=\fboxsep,
    framerule=\fboxrule,
    rulecolor=\color{red},
    xleftmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
    xrightmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule,
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\small\tt,
    keywordstyle=\color{cyan}\sf,
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
    commentstyle=\color{cyan},
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},
    tabsize=2,
    columns=flexible,
    morekeywords={LOW,HIGH,int,float,const,void,OUTPUT},
    classoffset=5,
    morekeywords={
        LiquidCrystal,begin,pinMode,setCursor,delay,print,
        clear, analogRead, delay, digitalWrite
    },
    keywordstyle={\color{arduinoOrange}},
    classoffset=6,
    otherkeywords={\#include, >, <},
    morekeywords={\#include,setup,loop,for,if, >, <},
    keywordstyle={\color{arduinoGrayGreen}}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(7,6,5,4,3,2);
int SENSOR;
float TEMPERATURA;
float SUMA;
const int MOTOR=13;

void setup() {
 lcd.begin(16,2);
 pinMode(MOTOR, OUTPUT);
 lcd.setCursor(1,0);
 lcd.print("COOLING SYSTEM");
 delay(3000);
 lcd.clear();
 }

void loop() {
  SUMA = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < 5; i++){
    SENSOR = analogRead(A0);
    TEMPERATURA = ((SENSOR*5000.0)/1023)/10;
    SUMA = TEMPERATURA + SUMA;
    delay(100);
  }
  if (TEMPERATURA > 35 ){
    lcd.clear();
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Ventilador ON");
  }
  else{
    lcd.clear();
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Ventilador OFF");
  }

 lcd.setCursor(0,0);
 lcd.print("Temp: ");
 lcd.print(SUMA/5.0,1);
 lcd.print(" C");
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: Arduino code highlight in LaTeX]

Does this answer your question?